# A BaseClass extends from Eloquent to handle complicated search condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Previous description of my problem is wrong. So I delete it and write a new one.

---

There are several tables, following are their structures

```
Table1: id, name
Table2: id, name, date1, date2
Table3: id, name, desc
maybe more tables...
```

And some html pages, each one references to a table. Every page has one or more search box to search data in related table. I use Ajax to handle the search work. I take some examples as below

```
Page    related table   search columns       http params
Page1:  Table1          id, name             q={"id": 1, "name":"bill"}
Page2:  Table2          id, date1, date2     q={"id": 1, "date1":"2014-7-19", "date2":"2014-7-20"}
Page3:  Table3          id, name             q={"id": 1, "name":"bill", "desc":"boss"}
```

Then I want to create a BaseModel extends from Eloquent, then all other specific Models extends from BaseModel.
I hope there will be a "search" method it can handle all of complicated search actions in BaseModel.

Comment: why do want the table name ?

Comment: I want to use it to execute some sql in BaseController

Comment: this->table = new model1;

Comment: Controller is supposed to handle request and return response, not to be coupled with any model. So it would be wise to let model/service/anythingYouLike to query the DB and just get the result in the controller. If you in fact ask, how to get model's table name, then `$model->getTable()` is your friend.

Comment: @deczo it seems that I did that in wrong place. Should I extends a BaseModel from Eloquent, then all models extends from BaseModel?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do. What is that query supposed to do and why?

Comment: there are several tables, and each table may have several different columns. I may search table1 for id=1, search table2 for id= 2 and name='bill', and table3 different columns. I use ajax to do the search , and put all search conditions into one json named q. when I search table1, it could be q={id:1}, and q={id:1, name:bill} when searching table2, and etc. I want the BaseClass can handle all these tables searching, when they have different search columns. Is it possible? @deczo

Comment: and must I ask a new question?

Comment: It seems that you need to build your query manually, depending on what you search for. So edit your question and describe exactly, what you expect and I'll help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to suggest a good solution since you don't really tell us, what needs to be done.

This is the most straightforward solution for you, using query scopes:

```
// BaseModel extending Eloquent Model
public function scopeSearch($query, $jsonSearch)
{
   $wheres = $this->parseSearch($jsonSearch);

   $query->where($wheres); // WHERE X = Y AND Z = A ...
}

protected function parseSearch($jsonSearch)
{
  // validate your input here, make sure it's correct according to your needs
}
```

Then:

```
// single result
AnyModel::search($yourJson)->first();

// collection
AnyModel::search($yourJson)->get();

// you can chain more methods if you like
AnyModel::search($yourJson)->where('x', 'y')->orderBy('x')->get();
```

Comment: yes, I forgot to said that I want to get all results in BaseModel. Then I don't need to write any code in child Model.

Comment: so the exact question is, how to use eloquent to handle several "where " we don't know how many they are

Comment: The code I showed you will do it, but it will only set `where x = y`, no `like`, `<`, `between` etc. Also you need to take care of validating input, so it's flat, ` level array, otherwise there could be unexpected results.